# how to implement gear joint in sprite kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-physics

The gear joint in Box2d is great, but I don't know how to implement that in Sprite Kit. Is there any solutions to implement the gear joint in Sprite Kit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the available Sprite-Kit joints :https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsjoint

[image]

As far as I can understand, there does not appear to be a direct correlation to Box2D's gear joint, which seems to make one body rotate when another body is rotated.

In that case, you might want to investigate overriding the didSimulatePhysics or didFinishUpdate methods to manually set the rotation of one object based upon the rotation of another object:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene/1519965-didsimulatephysics

https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skscene/1520269-didfinishupdate

It might be as simple as:

```
wheel2.zRotation = wheel1.zRotation
```

but if the gears have different numbers of teeth (thus different ratios), you'll have to do some calculations.